# storing objects in ResourceSelectionHistory of FilteredItemsSelectionDialog istead of string

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have been following the tutorial [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/package-summary.html). In the advanced tutorial ResourceSelectionHistory stores the selected items and the retrieves it when the dialog is relaunched. I wanted the ResourceSelectionHistory to store objects and not just strings, is there i way to do that. 
I also want the items to open in the editor when the user clicks on them. When I click on an item in the actual populated list it opens, but not when I click on the part showing history.

Thanks in advance

c yah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store strings, integers and Boolean to `IMemento`. You can cleverly utilize them to reveal the type of object. For example you can use `element.putInteger("objType", 1);` if your object is of say type A and `element.putInteger("objType", 2);` if its of type B.

Answer (score 0):

The `ResourceSelectionHistory` is very specific to this dialog and can only store resources. It stores them using the `IMemento` mechanism. Probably the only way you can do what you want is to make a copy of the class (`FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog`) and have your way with it. These dialogs tend to be pretty restrictive if you just follow the API.

Comment: Oops! sorry I forgot to add the hyperlink. Now added. Well I am following that tutorial. Is there some other way to do this. I have extended `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.`

Comment: You will probably need to make a subclass of `SelectionHistory` and then figure out how to store what you want in an `IMemento`. You will have to look into how `IMemento` works in terms of how to store your objects (you will probably need to somehow stringify your objects). I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your question about opening the objects from the workbench history. Perhaps you can edit your question to clarify this?

Comment: second part of question edited. The answer I am looking for is how to figure that out. Can you please provide link to any example of `IMemento`. Can we store objects in `IMemento` or it must be string only?